# Simultaneously uploading files to multiple ftp

Tags: ftp

I hve two remote servers :
suppose A and B

i hve my own local desktop through which i want to transfer my file simultaneously to Server A and B.
Is there any way or any tool through which i can do this?????

Comment: It might help if you identify which OS you are actually using...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ssh, then [parallel-ssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) will do it.
(debian package pssh)

If you really are using ftp, then I suggest thinking about using ssh.

Most windows ftp clients will let you script them. example: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you use ftp, and if by "simultaneously" you mean "with a single command", then just use curl to upload the file to several ftp servers

```
$ curl -T my_local_file -u userid:password ftp://servera/path/ ftp://serverb/path/
```

For small size files this will be near enough simultaneous anyway.

If the files are larger, or you really need closer synchronization, you could run several instances of curl in the background

```
$ for srv in servera serverb; do curl -T my_local_file -u userid:password ftp://${srv}/path& done
```